# How to address home directory and "my computer" in c# TreeView

Tags: c#, windows, treeview, filesystems

I am making a file system TreeView.  I want the initial four items to be

+Computer

+Desktop

+My Documents

+C:\

These will all be pre-populated so that when the + is clicked, the subdirectories appear and are immediately themselves populated. Works great for C:\ -- just like windows explorer.  But the other three just show as names.  They clearly don't relate to the actual filesystem locations. How do I add the other three filesystem locations?  I tried:

```
 TreeNode my_computer = new TreeNode("Computer");
 TreeNode desktop = new TreeNode(@"%UserProfile%\Desktop");
 TreeNode c_drive = new TreeNode(@"C:\");
 TreeNode my_documents = new TreeNode(@"%UserProfile%\My Documents");
```

and also without %UserProfile%.  Neither work.

Comment: They are virtual shell folders.  You have to enumerate them with native shell functions.  Oh joy.  Add a reference to c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll to get started on that.  Look at it with Object Browser to know what to google.

Comment: Also, you may want to rethink showing the absolute paths (if that's what you do). Avoid repretion and lengthy node text by puztting the relative path in the nod text and the absolute paths in the nodes' __tags__

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)